# Connect to sqlserver from heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, heroku, rails-activerecord, tiny-tds

i have a remote SQLSERVER instance wich i want to connect from my rails app hosted on heroku.
My gemfile:

```
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '~> 3.2.12'
gem 'tiny_tds'
```

database.yml

```
production:
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: dblib
  dataserver: host.database.windows.net
  database: items
  username: username@host
  password: password
  azure: true
```

production.rb

```
dbconfig = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read(File.join("config","database.yml"))).result)
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection dbconfig['production']
```

But i get the follwing error during the deploy process:

Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL

```
Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline

Running: rake assets:precompile

rake aborted!

LoadError: Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
```

It seems that Active record require sqlite3 but if i have tiny_tds it should use sql server.

In development env all works fine.
Sure there is something i am missing.

**UPDATE**

I've already set up the custom buildpack 
BUILDPACK_URL: https://github.com/firmhouse/heroku-buildpack-ruby-freetds.git
and the DATABASE_URL config var.

**UPDATE 2**

Making a pp of dbconfig var while deploing display this

```
{"production"=>
       {"adapter"=>"sqlite3",
       "database"=>"dbname",
       "username"=>"user",
       "password"=>"pass",
       "host"=>"127.0.0.1"}}
```

It seems that heroku overwrite my database.yml file, any suggestions?

**UPDATE 3**

I have set DATABASE_URL=sqlserver//user:pass@host:1433/database is this wrong?

Comment: Is that your whole Gemfile? Are you using sqlite for test/dev/staging? Is your Heroku environment set to something other than production? `heroku config:get RAILS_ENV` `heroku config:get RACK_ENV`

Comment: Nope the env is production, i noticed that printing dbconfig while deploing display this 
`{"production"=>
       {"adapter"=>"sqlite3",
       "database"=>"dbname",
       "username"=>"user",
       "password"=>"pass",
       "host"=>"127.0.0.1"}}` it seems that heroku overwrite my database.yml file

Comment: Yeah, heroku does that, so your loading it in production.rb isn't going to work. The buildpack appears to want the user/pass/host/port all in the DATABASE_URL, so it shouldn't be necessary to load it from yml like that.

Comment: @Unixmonkey yeah i also finally got this, then i setted up the DATABASE_URL var like this  heroku config:set DATABASE_URL=sqlserver//user:pass5@host:1433/database but printing the database.yml while deploing still print this `{"adapter"=>"sqlite3",        "database"=>"dbname",        "username"=>"user",        "password"=>"pass",        "host"=>"127.0.0.1"}`

Comment: Shouldn't matter what database.yml is if it isn't used. Remove those lines from production.rb, and set `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` to prevent trying to load the DB during asset compilation.

Comment: Thank you the deploy now goes well but heroku keeps trying to get my model data from his postgres database even if i use ActiveRecord.estabilsh_conenction with my custom config, so weired.

Answer (score 2):

I've faced same issue and finally found the answer.

You have to put the suffix below:

?encoding=uft-8&azure=true

So, your database_url will be like this:

**sqlserver://[user]:[password]@[server.database.windows.net]:1433/[database]?encoding=uft-8&azure=true**

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to [use a custom buildpack](http://blog.firmhouse.com/connecting-to-sql-server-from-heroku-with-freetds-here-is-how-on-cedar#).

> ### Using this FreeTDS buildpack on Heroku
>
> To use this buildpack you can pass in an option when creating your Heroku app:
>
> ```
> heroku create my_new_sqlserver_app --buildpack https://github.com/firmhouse/heroku-buildpack-ruby-freetds.git
> ```
>
> Or for current apps:
>
> ```
> heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/firmhouse/heroku-buildpack-ruby-freetds.git
> ```
>
> ### Configuring your database connection
>
> After creating your app or setting up your existing app to use the buildpack, you need to modify the `DATABASE_URL` config variable to point to your sqlserver instance. We currently use a SQL Server 2008 Express edition:
>
> ```
> heroku config:add DATABASE_URL=sqlserver://username:password@sqlserver_host:1433/database_name
> ```

Comment: Hi , i'am already using that custom buildback and i have also added the DATABASE_URL config var, going to update my answer.
Without that buildpack the tiny_tds gem could not be installed.